# to intercept a route change in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

We have a web service through which you can block a specific route, whenever user hits that particular route - what I want is if the web service has block it then that route should not get displayed.

Is it possible in react, react-router?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path={"/protected-path"} component={canAccess ? View : NoView} />
    <Route path="/404" component={NotFound} />
    <Redirect to="/404" />
</Switch>
```

`NoView` and `View` are react components. `canAccess` is a boolean value that checks user has access to that content.